# add web Reference in webservices issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have  developed a  web servcies in my local  system with name (inbox service).
when i did  add  web reference
i got  like this in my  web service  descpition file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<discovery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/">
  <contractRef ref="http://localhost:1518/popup-message/InboxService.asmx?wsdl" docRef="http://localhost:1518/popup-message/InboxService.asmx" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" />
  <soap address="http://localhost:1518/popup-message/InboxService.asmx" xmlns:q1="http://tempuri.org/" binding="q1:InboxServiceSoap" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
  <soap address="http://localhost:1518/popup-message/InboxService.asmx" xmlns:q2="http://tempuri.org/" binding="q2:InboxServiceSoap12" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
</discovery>
```

but when i deploy my  application (project) on   server.  i have  my project url like  this
 ex: http://abc.com, 
now  my webservice  is like this http://localhost:1518/popup-message/InboxService.asmx.
 if  i tied   to call method  from my page  it  is  not  working  what is  issue here

anyhelp would  be  great.
 thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you edited the url in web.config / app.config? Note that if the web-reference is in a dll (not the web layer itself) you might not even **see** the setting in web.config; in such cases, copy the setting from the dll's config in VS - into web.config. Note that dll configs don't really do anything, except provide somewhere to copy/paste that value from.

Comment: thanks  for the  replay Marc Gravell 
<appSettings>
 <add key="localhost.InboxService" value="http://localhost:1518/popup-message/InboxService.asmx"/>
 </appSettings>
 i have  this line  in my web config.  so  whta change  should i make here

Comment: change it to the address of the actual web-service... I cant tell you what that is.